# Bluez Mesh : Send : Get key_index

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez, mesh-network

I'm trying to make a Ble Mesh application using the bluez dbus api.

I have made a provisioner on a linux device and an unprovioned node on an other. When I have successfully provisioned my node with the provisioner, I need to send a message from the provisioner to the node.

For that I call the method `void Send(object element_path, uint16 destination, uint16 key_index, dict options, array{byte} data)` fom the `org.bluez.mesh.Node1` but I got this error :

`[org.bluez.mesh.Error.InvalidArgs] Key not found`

So my question is : How can I get or generate the key_index value ?

Comment: I have generate a key using `void CreateAppKey(uint16 net_index, uint16 app_index)` from the `org.bluez.mesh.Management1` interface but I have the same issue.